# How to update Nexus index of SpringSource repository

Tags: maven, nexus, springsource, maven-indexer

I added two SpringSource repositories to my Nexus instance

1. http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release
2. http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external

Configuration looks fine but I noticed that the index is always empty. So it is not possible to resolved depedencies for artifacts in this repository.

I can use *Browse Remote* to navigate to the artifact. So the artifact I need is in the repository but without an index, this is of no use it seems.

Also when I use search in Nexus I cannot find the artifact.

Why is there no index for these repositories?

How should these repositories be used?

Answer (score 0):

These repositories do not publish search indexes, you can test for this by trying to retrieve "/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties" through them:

http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release/.index/nexus-maven-repository-index.properties

Search indexes are an optional repository feature, they are not needed for artifact retrieval, they are used to support interactive search in UI's such as Nexus and m2Eclipse.  Nexus will be able to pull artifacts from these repositories without issue, and as artifacts are downloaded they will be added to the local search indexes.